# How to make do a centred title style where the line-breaks arranges the longest line at the bottom

Tags: css

I have a project where some pages have titles with a large font size. The title is dynamic and can be both one or 3-4 lines. For aesthetical reasons, I would love the title to be both centered and arrange the lines so that the longest (broadest) line goes to the bottom and the shortest goes to the top. Like the shape of a pyramid.

I don't know if this is possible in pure CSS or how I should get around this?

Any suggestions? :-)

[image]

Comment: I've read through [the specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-text-3/) and can't find a simple way of doing this. Searching the web only yielded [another person](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/15833/text-wrapping-fill-last-line-first) with the same need and no good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am no JQuery-wonder, but I have made this solution that fulfills my expectations for the alignment I requested. If your eyes hurt from this snippet, please give some suggestions for optimization. I already know that this won't work after resizing flexible elements.

I would of course prefer a solution made from pure CSS, so if you are listing W3C, the case `text-align: pyramid;` or even `text-align: simon;` (wink) is now officially requested.

```
$('#title').each(function(){

    var words = $(this).text().split(/\s+/);
    var total = words.length;
    var originalWidth = $(this).css("width");
    var maxWidth = $(this).width();
    var tempText = $(this);
    var string = "";
    var currentLineString = "";

    $(this).empty();
    tempText.css("width", "auto");

    for (i = 0; i < total; i++){

        var newString = words[total-i-1] + " " + currentLineString;
        tempText.text(newString);

        if (tempText.width() >= maxWidth) {
            tempText.text(currentLineString);
            maxWidth = tempText.width();
            string = currentLineString + "<br>" + string;
            currentLineString = "";
            i--;
        } else {
            currentLineString = newString;
        }
    }
    string = currentLineString + "<br>" + string;
                
    tempText.css("width", originalWidth);
    $(this).html(string);
});
```

Comment: how it work in code?

Comment: @M.RMRF what do you mean? It's just JQuery. Add a #title element and this JS to your page and see for yourself :-)

Answer (score 4):

How about shape-outside? We can limit the text boundaries with two triangle shapes, one on the left and another on the right

Do note: despite of the boundaries centering the text doesn't yield the desired  result, but on the contrary, justifying the text is not ideal either - the last line is not centered

```css
div{
  text-align:justify;
  font-size:20px;
  padding:15px;
  background:rgba(200,200,100,0.5);
}

left-shape {
  shape-outside: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 0 50%);
  width: 250px;
  height: 500px;
  float:left;
}

right-shape {
  shape-outside: polygon(100% 0, 0% 0, 100% 50%);
  width: 250px;
  height: 500px;
  float:right;

}
```

```html
<left-shape></left-shape> <right-shape></right-shape>

<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
```

Comment: With this it's worth mentioning that `<left-shape>` and `<right-shape>` are custom elements, which may (or may not) cause problems of some kind. But, otherwise, a nice answer. I was attempting to achieve this with pseudo-elements, but just couldn't get the `::after` pseudo-`<right-shape>` element to play nice.

Comment: Keep in mind the browser compatibility for `shape-outside`. Refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/shape-outside#browser_compatibility

Comment: @Alve I'm not sure how to read it, could you please explain what is "three-value" syntax?

Comment: @Alve edited the answer to introduce polygons rather than ellipses

Comment: This is actually a really good hack!

Comment: @nicael I appreciate your solution, but for my needs it's "too risky" with the justify-aligned lines. This could easily cause some weird gaps (like the first line in your example).

Answer (score 1):

## Possible javascript solution

If you can't find CSS solutions, here's a "somewhat solution" using javascript. It may not be the best approach and may have problems if the screen width decreases because we split the two strings using a breakpoint at the end. So this solution might work for you if you have enough spacing for the title, but you might want to consider using `whitespace: nowrap;` with this solution.

Try changing the offset to find the best result for yourself.

```js
// Get title element by ID:
var title = document.getElementById('title');

// Get content of the title:
var content = title.innerText;

// Where you want the text to be splitted from,
// 2 = middle, 3 = one third;
var offset = 2.5;

// Divide content by previously set amount:
var divided = Math.floor(content.length / offset);

// This gives the number of characters
// in the top part of the title
var count = content.indexOf(' ', divided);

// First part of the string,
// goes from start to "count" amount
var x = content.substring(0, count);

// Second part of the string, after count amount:
var y = content.substring(count);

// Place text back to the title,
// Using <br> might cause issues on mobile,
// but it's a rough idea what could be done.
title.innerHTML = x + "<br>" + y;
```

```css
#title{
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="title">This is an example of the line break I want</h1>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I'm not quite sure what the offset-variable means. I just want the line to break so every line is shorter than the line below it, which should result in a pyramid-shaped text. I tried your code to my page (used some other words than your example) which correctly made a line-break in a two-line title so the first line got one word shorter, but not at the correct place to make the first line the shorter than the second line.

Comment: Also this JS is based on substring lengths, so it would eventually only work with monospace fonts. I might try to experiment with some JS that measures the word lengths more accruate instead :-)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. You are very right, and I actually forgot to think about the word length and the font-family issues. I wish you good luck and I'm curious to see all the possible solutions to this =)